# Problems creating category Magento 2.1.7

Tags: category, url-key

my code to create a category is the following:

```
private function createCategory($name='',$parentId=2,$active=true,$description='',$metaTitle='',$metaKeywords='',$metaDescription='') 
{
    if(!isset($metaTitle))
    {
        $metaTitle = $name;
    }
    $categoryRepository = $this->categoryRepository;
    $category = $this->categoryFactory->create();
    $category->setName($name);
    $category->setParentId($parentId);
    $category->setIsActive($active);
    $category->setCustomAttributes([
        'description' => $description,
        'meta_title' => $metaTitle,
        'meta_keywords' => $metaKeywords,
        'meta_description' => $metaDescription,
    ]);
    $category->save();

    $categoryRepository->save($category);

    return $category->getId();

}
```

this error came up: [Magento\Framework\Exception\AlreadyExistsException]

URL Key for specified store already exists

Any solution for this?

Can't expect this to happen when importing data.

PD: Thanks for your time.